# Will CanActivate and CanActivateChild run at the same time if set?

Tags: angular, rxjs, canactivate

Currently my application will set a XHR to server to get user information.

I have set CanActivate and CanActivateChild like:

```
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthService],
    canActivateChild: [AuthService],
    children: [
        {
            path: 'a',
            component: AComponent,
        },
        { path: 'b1', component: B1Component },
        { path: 'b2', component: B2Component },
        {
            path: 'c',
            component: CComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
        },
        { path: 'd/create', component: DComponent },
        { path: 'd/:id', component: DComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]
}
```

When I go to `/a` that XHR sent twice so Angular will run CanActivate and CanActivateChild at the same time in parallel but not `CanActivate` first then `CanActivateChild`?

Comment: did you put your url to browser url like `domain.com/parent/a`, if you do this, it'll trigger twice. once for `parent`, and once for `a`.